# symfony 4: Request.getScheme() return http with X_FORWARDED_PROTO https

Tags: php, symfony, proxy, symfony4, traefik

from the `$_SERVER` php array:

```
$_SERVER['APP_ENV']                 prod
$_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']               0
$_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES']         172.16.0.0/12
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']   my.website.com
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT']   443
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']  https
```

from the HTTP Headers:

```
X-Forwarded-For     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
X-Forwarded-Host    my.website.com
X-Forwarded-Port    443
X-Forwarded-Proto   https
```

in `src/public/index.php`

```
if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}
```

in `/src/Controller/TestController.php`

```
class TestController 
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(  $request->getScheme() );
        return $response;
    }
}
```

output

```
http
```

but the expected output is

```
https
```

why symfony return the wrong http scheme?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the bad header name `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` returned by Traefik

Symfony recognize the `FORWARDED` or the `X_FORWARDED_PROTO`

[Source (for symfony 3.4 (deprecated code removed in 4.x)](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5971e2dd8f06eb9a949297ca772551d6fe34f2c1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L87)

```
protected static $trustedHeaders = array(
    self::HEADER_FORWARDED => 'FORWARDED',
    self::HEADER_CLIENT_IP => 'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
    self::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST => 'X_FORWARDED_HOST',
    self::HEADER_CLIENT_PROTO => 'X_FORWARDED_PROTO',
    self::HEADER_CLIENT_PORT => 'X_FORWARDED_PORT',
);
```

According to [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html) you must set the right Trusted Proxies in the public/index.php file like this (AWS ELB enabled, which recognize `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`

```
...
$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// tell Symfony about your reverse proxy

Request::setTrustedProxies(
// the IP address (or range) of your proxy
['192.0.0.1', '10.0.0.0/8'],

// trust *all* "X-Forwarded-*" headers
// Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL

// or, if your proxy instead uses the "Forwarded" header
// Request::HEADER_FORWARDED

// or, if you're using AWS ELB
Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB
);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 5 and up you can tell the framework to trust the reverse proxy by using these settings in `config/packages/framework.yaml`:

```
framework:

    # the IP address (or range) of your proxy
    trusted_proxies: '192.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/8'

    # trust *all* "X-Forwarded-*" headers
    trusted_headers: ['x-forwarded-for', 'x-forwarded-host', 'x-forwarded-proto', 'x-forwarded-port']
```

This will result in the correct https protocol when creating urls or using `$request->getScheme()`.

More about this in the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same output when you use the abstract class `AbstractController` ?

Like `class TestController extends AbstractController`